# Are there any C# collections where modification does not invalidate iterators?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, iterator

Are there any data structures in the C# Collections library where modification of the structure does not invalidate iterators?

Consider the following:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.Add( 1 );
myList.Add( 2 );
List<int>.Enumerator myIter = myList.GetEnumerator();
myIter.MoveNext();  // myIter.Current == 1
myList.Add( 3 );
myIter.MoveNext();  // throws InvalidOperationException
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need to modify the collection at the same time that you're reading from it? There may be another way to do what you want.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, take a look at the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace in .NET 4.0.

Note that for some of the collections in this namespace (e.g., `ConcurrentQueue<T>`), this works by only exposing an enumerator on a "snapshot" of the collection in question.

From [the MSDN documentation on `ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287144(v=VS.100).aspx):

> The enumeration represents a
>   moment-in-time snapshot of the
>   contents of the queue. It does not
>   reflect any updates to the collection
>   after GetEnumerator was called. The
>   enumerator is safe to use concurrently
>   with reads from and writes to the
>   queue.

This is not the case for all of the collections, though. `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, for instance, gives you an enumerator that maintains updates to the underlying collection between calls to `MoveNext`.

From [the MSDN documentation on `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287131(v=VS.100).aspx):

> The enumerator returned from the
>   dictionary is safe to use concurrently
>   with reads and writes to the
>   dictionary, however it does not
>   represent a moment-in-time snapshot of
>   the dictionary. The contents exposed
>   through the enumerator may contain
>   modifications made to the dictionary
>   after GetEnumerator was called.

If you *don't have* 4.0, then I think the others are right and there is no such collection provided by .NET. You can always build your own, however, by doing the same thing `ConcurrentQueue<T>` does (iterate over a snapshot).

Comment: Complete answer, thank you! Maybe you know how ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentStack take snapshots? Do they copy the whole collection to a new object and enumerate a copy? Or they have some other smart way of taking a snapshot?

Answer (score 8):

According to [this MSDN article on IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) the invalidation behaviour you have found is required by all implementations of IEnumerable.

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If 
>   changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting 
>   elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and the next call to 
>   MoveNext or Reset throws an InvalidOperationException. If the collection is 
>   modified between MoveNext and Current, Current returns the element that it is 
>   set to, even if the enumerator is already invalidated.

Comment: Well then, they have violated their own guidelines. All the collections in `System.Collections.Concurrent` allow modification of the collection between calls to `MoveNext`.

Comment: That's because the iterator traverses a snapshot of the collection, so that snapshot isn't modified while iterating.

Comment: That is what the documentation says, and I understand why that's a good idea for adding and removing elements, but it's unclear to me why modifying an element should invalidate the enumerator. I can understand why you might implement it that way, but not why you should.

Answer (score 5):

Supporting this behavior requires some pretty complex internal handling, so most of the collections don't support this (I'm not sure about the `Concurrent` namespace).

However, you can very well simulate this behavior using immutable collections. They don't allow you to *modify* the collection by design, but you can work with them in a slightly different way and this kind of processing allows you to use enumerator concurrently without complex handling (implemented in `Concurrent` collections).

You can implement a collection like that easily, or you can use `FSharpList<T>` from `FSharp.Core.dll` (not a standard part of .NET 4.0 though):

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections;

// Create immutable list from other collection
var list = ListModule.OfSeq(anyCollection);
// now we can use `GetEnumerable`
var en = list.GetEnumerable();

// To modify the collection, you create a new collection that adds 
// element to the front (without actually copying everything)
var added = new FSharpList<int>(42, list);
```

The benefit of immutable collections is that you can work with them (by creating copies) without affecting the original one, and so the behavior you wanted is "for free". For more information, there is a [great series by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Immutability/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to make a copy of the list before you iterate it:

```
var myIter = new List<int>(myList).GetEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not exist. ALl C# standard collections invalidate the numerator when the structure changes.

Answer (score -1):

Use a for loop instead of a foreach, and then you can modify it. I wouldn't advise it though....

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though. He's asking about iterators, not necessarily just indexed collections.

Comment: With the addition of the ElementAt() extension method, all collections can now be indexed into. I think this very much answers the questions....